# I can't join a site, because I am already a member

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I am on the iOS app. When I try to upvote a post on a site of which I am already a member, the following string of events happens:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

It thinks I am not a member, so it asks me to join. But since I am a member, it throws an error. If I click Cancel, nothing happens.

I have been using the app often and frequently. This is the first time it has happened. The only difference is that I am in a different state at the moment.  (In case something is tied to GPS, figured I'd provide that information.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.4.1 (currently in review).

I can't speak to why the app didn't think you're a member of the site, but there are some edge cases.  What I can say is if you get that popup again and you say join site, we won't offhandedly tell you that you did something wrong.  (We did!)  Instead, we'll see that you are already a member of the site, stick that in the list of sites you're a member of, and let you continue about your business.